# MySQL: How to select rows from one table between each interval taken from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

There are tables:

```
1.current_table:

date        value
02.10.2019  1
03.10.2019  2
04.10.2019  2
05.10.2019 -1
06.10.2019  1
07.10.2019  1
08.10.2019  2
09.10.2019  2
10.10.2019 -1
11.10.2019  2
12.10.2019  1

2.intervals

date_start  date_end
02.10.2019  04.10.2019  3
06.10.2019  09.10.2019  4
11.10.2019  12.10.2019  2
```

"intervals" table contains maximum length of an uninterrupted sequence of positive values.
How to select rows  from "current_table"  between each interval taken from "intervals" table (there are many of such intervals)?
So result should be:

```
date        value
02.10.2019  1
03.10.2019  2
04.10.2019  2   
06.10.2019  1
07.10.2019  1
08.10.2019  2
09.10.2019  2    
11.10.2019  2
12.10.2019  1
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  Why not just select from the first table `where value > 0`?  It returns the same result set without referencing the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first inclination is simply:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.value > 0;
```

Perhaps your intervals might overlap.  Or you might want to filter only for intervals in the second table.  If so, then `exists` is handy:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.value > 0 and
      exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.date between t2.date_start and t2.date_end
             );
```

This is overkill for your sample data, though.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables.
Only the rows that belong to an interval in table `intervals` will be returned:

```
select t.* 
from current_table t inner join intervals i
on t.date between i.date_start and i.date_end
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/umc2ugie8PpR5hZa7dS3jn/0).
Or with `EXISTS`:

```
select t.* 
from current_table t 
where exists (
  select 1 from intervals i
  where t.date between i.date_start and i.date_end
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/umc2ugie8PpR5hZa7dS3jn/1).
Results:

```
| date       | value |
| ---------- | ----- |
| 2019-02-10 | 1     |
| 2019-03-10 | 2     |
| 2019-04-10 | 2     |
| 2019-06-10 | 1     |
| 2019-07-10 | 1     |
| 2019-08-10 | 2     |
| 2019-09-10 | 2     |
| 2019-11-10 | 2     |
| 2019-12-10 | 1     |
```